# New UUID generated on each run

Tags: swift, uuid

I have this code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
let udid = UUID().uuidString
```

But each time I run the application I get a new generated `UUID`. How come?

I need the same ID for each user to be able to identify them so should I save this in a UserDefault or how should I do to uniquely identify a user even when the user restarts the application?

Comment: "But each time I run the application I get a new generated UUID. How come?" From the doc "Create and returns a new UUID with RFC 4122 version 4 random bytes.". Are you looking for identifierVendor or assimilated?

Comment: I´m looking for a way to uniquely identify a user and have an ID for that user. If the user uninstalls the application then I can get a new ID otherwise I want the same ID for the user and not a new one on each restart of the application.

Comment: To the downvoter, feel free to downvote if you feel like it but leave a comment to why you downvoted and give me feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for what you're trying to do is `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor`. This returns exactly the kind of UUID you're describing (and is intended for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

According to [UUID documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid)

> `init()` Initializes a new UUID with RFC 4122 version 4 random bytes.
>
> `var uuidString: String` 
>   Returns a string created from the UUID, such as
>   “E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F”

So every time when you're calling `let udid = UUID().uuidString`, it returns the new UUID.
If you need to have the same UUID, just save it and read next time when you'll need it.
E.g:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(udid, forKey: "MY_UUID")
```

and next time check the UserDefaults for the value and create one if needed:

```
if let udid = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "MY_UUID") as? String, !udid.isEmpty {
     // Use it...
} else {
    let udid = UUID().uuidString
    UserDefaults.standard.set(udid, forKey: "MY_UUID")
}
```

But, please, be aware that UserDefaults are cleared on app uninstall. So you can use Keychain to save UUID if you need to have access to if after re-install. Also, you can use libs, like [FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID)

Answer (score 0):

Save the generated UUID in application settings.
When uninstall, its will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go!

```
func getUUID() -> String {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    if (userDefaults.string(forKey: "uuid") ?? "").isEmpty == true {
        userDefaults.set(UUID().uuidString,forKey: "uuid")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
        return userDefaults.string(forKey: "uuid") ?? ""
    } else {
        return userDefaults.string(forKey: "uuid") ?? ""

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@State private var uuid: String = {
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["uuid" : UUID().uuidString])
    return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uuid") ?? ""
}()
{
    didSet {UserDefaults.standard.set(uuid, forKey: "uuid")}
}
```

The code above will help you do this in SwiftUI. It checks to see whether the string is already registered. If not, it assigns a UUID to it. The UUID will stay the same unless the app is deleted and reinstalled.

This generates a random UUID, not a device identifier. The other answer accepted above will return the device identifier.